# Model Form not displaying

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I am using modelform for a model department is not working. (BTW,I have a custom user model also in users app of same project). All I am getting is a 'Test up' button in the html output. Also, Change E-mail and Signout are displaying may be consequence to usage of allauth in middleware. I don't know whether allauth is interfering with this or not (hope not).I have added department model to admin but there is some strange thing appearing in admin described below

I have tried to debug with many ways.

Here is the model

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from users.models import User,UserProfile

# Create your models here.
class department(models.Model):
    Dept_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Inventory'),
        (2, 'Dispatch'),
        )
    dept_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=Dept_CHOICES,default=1,unique=False),
    HOD = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,),
    Invest = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,),

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dept_type
```

Here is the view code

```
def add_model(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = departForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.save()
            return redirect('/')

    else:

        form = departForm()

        return render(request, "test.html", {'form': form})
```

base.html

```
<!-- templates/base.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
  <body>
  <main>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

test.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class = "container">
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button type="submit">Test up</button>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

admin.py

```
from core1.models import department

# Register your models here.

@admin.register(department)
class DepartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

output in **admin** of the site is a single field with strange name of

```
<django.db.models.fields.PositiveSmallIntegerField>
```

For additional info, I am using class view and function view in the same views.py file. Hope it is allowed.

I expect the form to be displayed
Tried form.as_p but getting

```
<<bound method BaseForm.as_p of <departForm bound=False, valid=False, fields=()>>
```

Tried form.valid

```
<bound method BaseForm.is_valid of <departForm bound=False, valid=False, fields=()>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved on my own !

1. I checked Admin site. There is no department model displaying. This means either I am not migrating properly or my department model has an issue
2. My department model has all fields ending with a , (comma). Same removed and made the model more robust and without error.
3. Removed all migrations and done fresh migrate
4. Modified Admin as follows

```
# Register your models here.
class departmentadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['HOD', 'Investigator', 'dept_type']
    list_display = ('HOD','Investigator','dept_type')
    pass

admin.site.register(department, departmentadmin)
```

Now admin also displaying dpartment and form also displaying departments with required out put..